# How to share $profit$ with $employees$ according to their "$score$"?

Tags: calculus

I need to split $1.000 between 5 employees according to their scores.

Suposing:

- Employee 1: 3445 points.
- Employee 2: 222 points.
- Employee 3: 222 points (also).
- Employee 4: 1994 points.
- Employee 5: 4472 points.

The logic is "the more points, the more you receive." How to calculate that?

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you trying to divide the money proportionally to the scores? What have you tried so far, and what exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $p$ to be the total *profit* to be shared and you want to share it **proportional** to employee scores, then, for example, the share of Employee 1, say $s_1$, would be:
$$s_1=p\times\frac{\text{score of Employee 1}}{\text{sum of all scores}}=p\times\frac{3445}{10355}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be the total number of points, i.e.,
$$N=\sum_i n_i =3445+222+222+1994+4472=10355,$$ where $n_i$ is the number of points employee $i$ has.

Let $w_i$ be how big a percent employee $i$ gets of the $1000.

You then have $$w_i=n_i/N.$$

For instance, employee 3 has 222 points, therefore s/he should get $\frac{222}{10355}\approx 2.1\%$ of the $1000.